# Looking for a word like "gearhead" but for gadgets

Tags: single-word-requests

The question is kind of self-explanatory. I'm looking for a single word along the lines of "gearhead" that could describe a person who is really into *tech* and *gadgets*, rather than cars. Upon Googling "gearhead," there were a few examples where the word was used more in reference to what I'm looking for, but more often than not it's used in the context of vehicles and I was hoping to avoid using it...

> Person 1: (gestures vaguely) "Look at that guy over there."
>
> *person in question appears to be carrying various electronic devices, has a fancy phone, etc.
>
> Person 2: "You mean that [gearhead]?"

Comment: Yeah, I've heard "gadget-head" a number of times, possibly more often than "gear-head" (though not recently).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-head#English) one may append "-head" to make up new words. It says:

> Etymology 2.  Combining form of the noun head. Suffix: -head
>   **Used to form (usually derogatory) words for people who regularly have their mind focused upon a particular subject, activity, or a specified drug or other substance, or who are addicted in some way.**
>   *motorhead, metalhead, pothead*
>   Used to form words to describe people who are fans of something, especially music.

And this leads us to ...

1) **Techhead**

> Tech-head - An enthusiast for or expert in technology, now especially computer technology.
>   — [OD](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tech-head)

2) **Gadgethead**

This seems widely used with many Google hits, though I haven't seen it in an 'official' dictionary. Meaning is obvious anyway e.g. from [NY Mag](http://nymag.com/thecut/2015/11/gift-guide-gadgets.html):

> 15 Techie Gifts for Your Favorite Gadget Head

Answer (score 5):

Don't stray from the gadget. Go with gadgeteer.

> Gadgeteer NOUN
>
> I'm not a gadgeteer; I don't enjoy the equipment as an end in itself.
>
> Most of my fellow-divers were keen gadgeteers.
>
> The gadgeteer takes items he finds during his adventures and uses his Engineering skill to transform them into gadgets. 
>   - [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gadget?q=gadgeteer#gadget__5)

Comment: Indeed, the first word that came to mind.

Comment: Never heard of it. Regional usage perhaps?

Comment: To my ear, _gadgeteer_ sounds like someone who _makes_ or _invents_ gadgets. I don't think that's what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 4):

How about: **Technophile**

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/technophile):

> someone who likes and enjoys technology and modern machines (such as computers)

and

> an enthusiast of technology

As with @k1eran's answer regarding "-head", "-phile" may be appended to words to create new words for describing someone who has a passion for a particular field.

From [wikitionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-phile):

> Suffix
> -phile
>
> Forming nouns and adjectives meaning "loving", "friendly", or
> "friend".
>
> *Scott is such a bibliophile that he won't even put that book
> down.*

Answer (score 2):

He's a **[Gadget geek](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Gadget%20Geek)**.

A person who is obsessed with new gadgets.

You may also use **[Tech-savvy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tech-savvy)**, if that person is highly proficient in handling new technologies and devices.

Answer (score 2):

A propeller head (sometimes shortened to prop head or prophead ) is jargon for someone who is exceptionally, perhaps weirdly bright or knowledgeable, especially in some technical field. In computers, according to The New Hacker's Dictionary , it's a synonym for computer geek . The term refers to the child's beanie cap that comes with a spinning propeller sticking out of the top.